# Mean over a pandas DataFrame object including statistical significance after a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Imagine I've got this pandas `DataFrame`:

```
  Class Val
0     A   1
1     B   1
2     B   1
3     B   1
4     B   0
```

And I want to do the mean of the values grouped by `Class`, BUT having in mind  statistical significance of the values so, if `B` had a lot of `Val` equal to `1` the result value of the mean of `B` will overcome the result value of the mean of `A` because it only has one observation.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Val': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]})
print(df.groupby('Class').agg(['mean', 'count']))
```

You will have to expand on how you decide which to use, but this provides you with the basic info you need to do that.